# Detect iPad orientation change

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ipad, screen-orientation

How to detect with [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) or [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) when user turns iPad from vertical position to horizontal or from horizontal to vertical?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange', function(event) {
  alert('new orientation:' + event.orientation);
});
```

Comment: On the Ipad 1 I'm testing with the event object does not have an orientation property, but the window object does, so I had to use `orientation` rather than `event.orientation`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer @Karl-Bjørnar Øie.It solved my issue in the best way!

Comment: @Mrunal in pageLoad() or similar function that will always be called before the page will actually be interacted with.

Answer (score 20):

You can detect the orientation change event using the following code:

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on('orientationchange', function(event) {
        console.log(orientation);
    });
});
```

---

**Check if device is in portrait mode**

```
function isPortrait() {
    return window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `console.log(event.orientation)` ?   (event missing)

Answer (score 12):

In Javascript:

```
<button onclick="detectIPadOrientation();">What's my Orientation?</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onorientationchange = detectIPadOrientation;
 function detectIPadOrientation () {

    if ( orientation == 0 ) {
     alert ('Portrait Mode, Home Button bottom');
    }
    else if ( orientation == 90 ) {
     alert ('Landscape Mode, Home Button right');
    }
    else if ( orientation == -90 ) {
     alert ('Landscape Mode, Home Button left');
    }
    else if ( orientation == 180 ) {
     alert ('Portrait Mode, Home Button top');
    }
 }
</script>
```

Or for including additional stylesheets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:portrait)" href="portrait.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:landscape)" href="landscape.css">
```

Both taken from: http://favo.asia/2010/07/detecting-ipad-orientation-using-javascript/ which, FYI, was the first result on Google for 'detect ipad orientation javascript'...

Comment: Now, this question is at the top in Google :-)

Comment: @simon where are you getting the orientation variable from?

Answer (score -1):

```
function detectIPadOrientation (orientation) {  
   if ( orientation == 0 ) {  
    alert ('Portrait Mode, Home Button bottom');  
   }  
   else if ( orientation == 90 ) {  
    alert ('Landscape Mode, Home Button right');  
   }  
   else if ( orientation == -90 ) {  
    alert ('Landscape Mode, Home Button left');  
   }  
   else if ( orientation == 180 ) {  
    alert ('Portrait Mode, Home Button top');  
   }  
}

window.onorientationchange = detectIPadOrientation;
```

Comment: Am I missing something? where are you getting orientation variable?

Comment: Was this just a copy+paste of Simon's answer?

Comment: @GreySage who is Simon?

Comment: The user with the answer above yours.